# Problems connecting to WCF with in-code client

Tags: .net, wcf

I'm trying to connect to a WCF service with an in-code configured client. The host is configured through web.config file. I get exception "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed." I've test it with self-hosting and it worked but I can't get it too work when it's running on it's own. I'm trying to get it too work with VS devenv local hosting.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/MyService" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
     </service>
     </services>
     <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
            </behavior> 
         </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

---

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/MyService");
var address = new EndpointAddress(uri);
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), address);
IMyService service = factory.CreateChannel();

service.DoSomething(); <-- fails here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently when using a non-self hosted option then the client endpointaddress must include .svc at the end.